# Create multiple columns in R based on other column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have 2 columns in data frame , please refer to below

```
no  value
1   A_0.9
1   B_0.8
1   C_0.7
1   D_0.7
2   B_0.9
2   D_0.8
2   A_0.7
2   C_0.7
```

I want to create new data frame as below

```
no  value1  value2  value3  value4
1   A_0.9   B_0.8   C_0.7   D_0.7
2   B_0.9   D_0.8   A_0.7   C_0.7
```

i.e: for each unique value in column "no" there will be multiple columns created using data in column "value"

Comment: Would be interesting to better reformat your data so that people can more easily see what the columns are. Personally, I cannot see a two-column dataframe there in your representation. Doing so could higher the chances of receiving a proper answer.

Comment: Okay, I copied data from excel but when I posted the question it took text format. I will copy and paste col one by one Let me know if this helps to understand the data ad requirement, I have 2 columns in data frame , please refer to below
Col 1 : no
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
Col 2 : value
A_0.9
B_0.8
C_0.7
D_0.7
B_0.9
D_0.8
A_0.7
C_0.7
I want to create new data frame as below Col 1: no
1
2
Col 2: value1
A_0.9
B_0.9
Col 3: value2
B_0.8
D_0.8
Col 4: value3
C_0.7
A_0.7
Col 5: value4
D_0.7
C_0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`, we can create a sequence per unique `value` by `no` with `rleid()`, and consequently use it to `dcast()` the data to wide format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[, nr := rleid(value),by = no], no ~ nr)
#  no     1     2     3     4
#1  1 A_0.9 B_0.8 C_0.7 D_0.7
#2  2 B_0.9 D_0.8 A_0.7 C_0.7
```

Or with the [dev version (1.9.7)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table`, the following is possible, thanks @Arun!

```
dcast(setDT(df), no ~ rowid(no, prefix = 'value'))
#   no value1 value2 value3 value4
#1:  1  A_0.9  B_0.8  C_0.7  D_0.7
#2:  2  B_0.9  D_0.8  A_0.7  C_0.7
```

Comment: Thanks mtoto for sharing this.

Comment: you're welcome, please bear in mind that the this solution is about x400 faster than the `unstack` approach.

Comment: I have tried and noticed that above code will be very useful for unequal observation for each groups available in column "no" in data frame example which I shared. Codes which you shared worked perfectly for smaller data set, but when I tried these codes on large data set, I got message "Using 'nr' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'". Not sure what was these and I didn't get the requried dataframe. Below are codes which I used. check <- dcast(setDT(raw.data)[, nr := rleid(Value),by = no], no ~ nr)

Comment: I use below syntax post which I got above message then I was able to get required results. check <- reshape(raw.data, idvar="Ticket..", timevar="nr", direction="wide"). Is there any reason why first line was not worked to convert data frame in required format?

Comment: try `data.table::dcast` at the beginnig of the line

Comment: I tried used data.table::dcast at the beginning, modified code to "check <- data.table::dcast(setDT(raw.data)[, nr := rleid(Value),by = no], no ~ nr)", but still not able to get requried results and got the same message "Using 'nr' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'". It does modifies raw.data by adding nr column and inserting sequence 1,23,...for unique records in col "no", using this revised data frame I could use code "check <- reshape(raw.data, idvar="Ticket..", timevar="nr", direction="wide")" to get requried results

Answer (score 2):

```
t(unstack(df, value ~ no))
#   [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#X1 "A_0.9" "B_0.8" "C_0.7" "D_0.7"
#X2 "B_0.9" "D_0.8" "A_0.7" "C_0.7"
```

To tidy the above output to fit your data,

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(t(unstack(df, value ~ no)))
 names(df1)[-1] <- paste0('value', 2:ncol(df1)-1)
 rownames(df1) <- NULL
 df1 <- add_rownames(df1, 'no')  #from dplyr package
 #    no value1 value2 value3 value4
 #  (chr) (fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)
 #1     1  A_0.9  B_0.8  C_0.7  D_0.7
 #2     2  B_0.9  D_0.8  A_0.7  C_0.7
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, I just have one query there might be more than 4 values for each unique number in col "no", so for naming the column is there any other way

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I able to put column names, One last question, when I executed code add fist column , it takes values 1,2,... in first col, First column not taking values in col "no". Is there any way I can have values in col "no" in first col, these does appear in id col when I executed first two commands of unstack

Comment: I got it I have commented  rownames(df1) <- NULL
then able to get results required, Thanks again for help

Answer (score 0):

I would use `reshape` library, which wraps a nice set of data manipulation functions. Example to accomplish your task:

```
n = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
x = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
# Just to create the column names you showed in the example
columns = rep(paste("value", 1:4, sep=""), 2)
data = data.frame(n, columns, x)
cast(data, n~columns)
```

Comment: The way you define `columns` here is only appropriate for the example dataset, and thus not scalable.